# On Gitbash - Bower : ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH --

Tags: git

I have installed GIT with the option enabled "Run Windows commands ..."
and set the PATH to ;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\cmd  and in other to check if git is working i'm writing `git` in the `cmd`.

It's not working.

any idea about what i am doing wrong?

Thank you.
KRs. BTR

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the [git-scm installer](https://git-scm.com/download/win)?

This is what it made for, to install git on windows machine. In the installer you have options is you want to add it to your `cmd` & path.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem using this command in the console prompt:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;
```